# How do I install and configure a DHCP server?

Tags: server, dhcp

How to install and configure a DHCP server in Ubuntu 12.04?

I need a step-by-step tutorial if somebody has one.

Comment: not the most user-friend but: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/dhcp3-server

Comment: This might be the same but ... http://comtech247.net/2012/05/01/how-to-set-up-a-dhcp-server-on-ubuntu-server-12-04-lts/

Comment: "Note that, in Ubuntu 12.04, ISC DHCP server is a transitional package for dhcp3-server."
http://wiki.openelec.tv/index.php?title=Network_Boot_-_NFS#Configure_DHCP

Comment: I prefer `dnsmasq`, a DNS and DHCP server with simple configuration file syntax.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

The first thing You need to do is install the packages we need.

Open up a terminal and type:

```
sudo apt-get install isc-dhcp-server
```

There are two main files `/etc/default/isc-dhcp-server` and `/etc/dhcp/dhcpd.conf` which we will need to configure so lets take the first.

Open up a terminal and using your favorite text editor type:

```
sudo vim /etc/default/isc-dhcp-server
```

You should get the following:

```
#Defaults for dhcp initscript
#sourced by /etc/init.d/dhcp
#installed at /etc/default/isc-dhcp-server by the maintainer scripts
#
#This is a POSIX shell fragment
#
#On what interfaces should the DHCP server (dhcpd) serve DHCP requests"
#Separate multiple interfaces with spaces, e.g. “eth0 eth1".
INTERFACES="eth0"
```

Replace **eth0** above with the name of your network interface that you want the server to lease addresses on. Onto the next file.

Open up a terminal and type:

```
sudo vim /etc/dhcp/dhcpd.conf
```

which should give you the output below.

```
#
#Sample configuration file for ISC dhcpd for Debian
#
#Attention: If /etc/ltsp/dhcpd.conf exists, that will be used as
#configuration file instead of this file.
#
#
....
option domain-name “example.org”;
option domain-name-servers ns1.example.org, ns2.example.org;
option domain-name “comtech.com”;
default-lease-time 600;
max-lease-time 7200;
log-facility local7;
subnet 10.0.0.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 {
range 10.0.0.150 10.0.0.253;
option routers 10.0.0.2;
option subnet-mask 255.255.255.0;
option broadcast-address 10.0.0.254;
option domain-name-servers 10.0.0.1, 10.0.0.2;
option ntp-servers 10.0.0.1;
option netbios-name-servers 10.0.0.1;
option netbios-node-type 8;
 ......
}
```

This needs a little bit of explaining.

> 1. Adjust your settings according to your network requirements.
> 2. The option domain name is your dns zone name. For example mine is set to comtech.com.
> 3. Range should be the range of ip addresses that you want the server to give out to clients.

Now restart the dhcp service by typing:

```
sudo service isc-dhcp-server restart
```

Thats it!! Your dhcp server should be running, however it is best to check. Open up a terminal and type:

```
sudo netstat -uap
```

which will show you something like the following (look for `dhcpd`, `nmbd`, and `named`):

```
Active Internet connections (servers and established)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address State PID/Program name
udp        0      0 10.0.0.255:netbios-dgm  *:*                   1016/nmbd
udp        0      0 10.0.0.255:netbios-ns   *:*                   1016/nmbd
udp        0      0 *:bootps                *:*                   4525/dhcpd
udp        0      0 *:netbios-dgm           *:*                   1016/nmbd
udp        0      0 *:netbios-ns            *:*                   1016/nmbd
udp        0      0 chris-desktop:domain    *:*                   1273/named
udp        0      0 chris-desktop.lo:domain *:*                   1273/named
udp        0      0 chris-deskt:netbios-dgm *:*                   1016/nmbd
udp        0      0 chris-deskto:netbios-ns *:*                   1016/nmbd
udp6       0      0 [::]:domain             [::]:*                1273/named
```

Comment: Just a word of caution, make sure to use `/etc/dhcp/dhcpd.conf` and **not** `/etc/dhcp3/dhcpd.conf`

Comment: When I restart the service this message is shown: `stop: Unknown instance: isc-dhcp-server start/running, process 3027`. I am not able to start the service. I use Ubuntu 13.10.

Comment: good . but make sure you've assigned static IP b4 starting DHCP service

Comment: This is not so hard, but using `dnsmasq` is easier if you ask me.

Answer (score 5):

Additional things can be included in the accepted answer

1. Assign static IP before starting isc-dhcp-server service .
2. You can reserve IP for devices like printers and linux machines by adding MAC id in the below format inside the particular subnet.

   ```
   ------
   host bla1 { 
           hardware ethernet DD:GH:DF:E5:F7:D7;
           fixed-address 10.0.0.10;
   }
   ----
   ```

   [Dhcp3-server Community Wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/dhcp3-server)

   [Ubuntu DHCP server](http://www.krizna.com/ubuntu/setup-dhcp-server-ubuntu-14-04/)

Answer (score 1):

From the Ubuntu community page [**dhcp3-server**](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/dhcp3-server) by [Contributors to the Ubuntu documentation wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/License):

> ## Dynamic Host Configuration Protocol (DHCP)
>
> The Dynamic Host Configuration Protocol (DHCP) is a network service
>   that enables host computers to be automatically assigned settings from
>   a server as opposed to manually configuring each network host.
>   Computers configured to be DHCP clients have no control over the
>   settings they receive from the DHCP server, and the configuration is
>   transparent to the computer's user.
>
> ## Installation
>
> At a terminal prompt, enter the following command to install dhcpd:
>
> ```
> sudo apt-get install dhcp3-server
> ```
>
> You will probably need to change the default configuration by editing
>   /etc/dhcp3/dhcpd.conf to suit your needs and particular configuration.
>
> You also need to edit `/etc/default/dhcp3-server` to specify the
>   interfaces dhcpd should listen to. By default it listens to eth0.
>
> ## Configuration
>
> The error message the installation ends with might be a little
>   confusing, but the following steps will help you configure the
>   service:
>
> Most commonly, what you want to do is assign an IP address randomly.
>   This can be done with settings as follows:
>
> ```
> nano -w /etc/dhcp3/dhcpd.conf
> ```
>
> ```
> # Sample /etc/dhcpd.conf
> # (add your comments here) 
> default-lease-time 600;
> max-lease-time 7200;
> option subnet-mask 255.255.255.0;
> option broadcast-address 192.168.1.255;
> option routers 192.168.1.254;
> option domain-name-servers 192.168.1.1, 192.168.1.2;
> option domain-name "mydomain.example";
>
> subnet 192.168.1.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 {
> range 192.168.1.10 192.168.1.100;
> range 192.168.1.150 192.168.1.200;
> }
> ```
>
> This will result in the DHCP server giving a client an IP address from
>   the range 192.168.1.10-192.168.1.100 or 192.168.1.150-192.168.1.200.
>   It will lease an IP address for 600 seconds if the client doesn't ask
>   for a specific time frame. Otherwise the maximum (allowed) lease will
>   be 7200 seconds. The server will also "advise" the client that it
>   should use 255.255.255.0 as its subnet mask, 192.168.1.255 as its
>   broadcast address, 192.168.1.254 as the router/gateway and 192.168.1.1
>   and 192.168.1.2 as its DNS servers.
>
> If you need to specify a WINS server for your Windows clients, you
>   will need to include the netbios-name-servers option, e.g.
>
> ```
> nano -w /etc/default/dhcp3-server
> ```
>
> ```
> option netbios-name-servers 192.168.1.1;
> ```
>
> ## dhcp3-server and multiple interfaces
>
> ### multiple interfaces example
>
> #### Interface
>
> ```
> nano -w /etc/network/interfaces
> ```
>
> ```
> auto lo
> iface lo inet loopback
>
> mapping hotplug
>         script grep
>         map eth1
>
> iface eth1 inet dhcp
>
> auto eth0
> iface eth0 inet static
>     address 10.152.187.1
>     netmask 255.255.255.0
>
> auto wlan0
>   iface wlan0 inet static
>     address 192.168.1.1
>     netmask 255.255.255.0
>     up     /sbin/iwconfig wlan0 mode TTTTTT && /sbin/iwconfig wlan0 enc
> restricted && /sbin/iwconfig wlan0 key [Y] XXXXXXXX && /sbin/iwconfig
> wlan0 essid SSSSSSSS
>
> auto eth1
> ```
>
> #### Select Interface card
>
> ```
> nano -w /etc/default/dhcp3-server
> ```
>
> ```
> INTERFACES="wlan0 eth0"
> ```
>
> #### Configure Subnet
>
> ```
> nano -w /etc/dhcp3/dhcpd.conf
> ```
>
> ```
> ddns-update-style none;
> log-facility local7;
>
> subnet 192.168.1.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 {
>
>         option routers                  192.168.1.1;
>         option subnet-mask              255.255.255.0;
>         option broadcast-address        192.168.1.255;
>         option domain-name-servers      194.168.4.100;
>         option ntp-servers              192.168.1.1;
>         option netbios-name-servers     192.168.1.1;
>         option netbios-node-type 2;
>         default-lease-time 86400;
>         max-lease-time 86400;
>
>         host bla1 {
>                 hardware ethernet DD:GH:DF:E5:F7:D7;
>                 fixed-address 192.168.1.2;
>         }
>         host bla2 {
>                 hardware ethernet 00:JJ:YU:38:AC:45;
>                 fixed-address 192.168.1.20;
>         }
> }
>
> subnet  10.152.187.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 {
>
>         option routers                  10.152.187.1;
>         option subnet-mask              255.255.255.0;
>         option broadcast-address        10.152.187.255;
>         option domain-name-servers      194.168.4.100;
>         option ntp-servers              10.152.187.1;
>         option netbios-name-servers     10.152.187.1;
>         option netbios-node-type 2;
>
>         default-lease-time 86400;
>         max-lease-time 86400;
>
>         host bla3 {
>                 hardware ethernet 00:KK:HD:66:55:9B;
>                 fixed-address 10.152.187.2;
>         }
> }
> ```
>
> #### Check Route
>
> ```
> ip route
> ```
>
> ```
> 192.168.1.0/24 dev wlan0  scope link
> 82.16.TT.0/24 dev eth1  scope link
> 10.152.187.0/24 dev eth0  scope link
> default via 82.16.TT.UU dev eth1
> ```