# How to set up a linux server as a router

Tags: networking

**Motivation:**

I want to use my linux server instead of the average wireless router for several reasons

1. I want to learn how to set up a more complete server on linux
2. I don't want to have a modem, connected to a router, connected to a network switch
3. I am sick and tired of having to unplug my router every 10 days because it just hangs
4. I am sick and tired of buying routers only to realize they are missing something crucial, like port forwarding or static ip addressing (dhcp)

**Set up:**

Ultimately, the connection will come into a modem, and straight into my server through `eth0`, then `eth1` will output to a network switch which all other client computers will connect to via ethernet cables (forget wireless for the moment). Currently, however, I am in an office building, and I have the connection coming into a modem, which goes into a router, which goes into a network switch, which then goes into `eth0` as specified above.

**Current Tutorials:**

I looked at some tutorials ([Ubuntu tutorial](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Router) is the best one), and I have looked at some of the router questions here (ie. [this one](https://askubuntu.com/questions/225466/second-nic-on-dual-homed-server-not-working)), but they all gloss over several key concepts, like:

- What is `eth1`'s relation to `eth0`? In `/etc/network/interfaces` do I have to tell `eth1` to use `eth0` as the `network` (generally it is the actual physical router address)?
- Do I have to do anything to instruct `eth1` to take the internet that comes into `eth0` and pass it onto whoever wants it in the network switch?

**Current Approach:**

Here is my `/etc/network/interfaces` file on the server:

```
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth0
   iface eth0 inet static
   address 192.168.1.70
   netmask 255.255.255.0
   broadcast 192.168.1.255
   network 192.168.1.0
   gateway 192.168.1.1
   dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8

auto eth1
   # iface eth1 inet dhcp
   iface eth1 inet static
   address 192.168.7.0
   netmask 255.255.255.0
   broadcast 192.168.1.255
   network 192.168.1.0
```

And `ifconfig` tells me that both NICs are working fine:

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 20:cf:30:55:a0:5f  
          inet addr:192.168.1.70  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::22cf:30ff:fe55:a05f/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:11297 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:16639 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:948633 (948.6 KB)  TX bytes:1274685 (1.2 MB)

eth1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:11:95:f7:f4:6d  
          inet addr:192.168.7.0  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::211:95ff:fef7:f46d/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:243 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:3231 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:29934 (29.9 KB)  TX bytes:213055 (213.0 KB)
          Interrupt:21 

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:5348 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:5348 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:470737 (470.7 KB)  TX bytes:470737 (470.7 KB)

wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr bc:f6:85:f8:70:5c  
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
```

And here is what `route -n returns` on the server:

```
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 eth1
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
192.168.7.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth1
```

Then on the client I have

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
iface eth0 inet dhcp
```

But it is not being assigned an ip address.

**EDIT:** Here is the isc-dhcp-server configuration file located at `/etc/dhcp3/dhcpd.con` which I copied mostly from [this site](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/isc-dhcp-server).

```
# Sample /etc/dhcpd.conf                                                                                                                                                  
# (add your comments here) 
default-lease-time 600;
max-lease-time 7200;
option subnet-mask 255.255.255.0;
option broadcast-address 192.168.1.255;
option routers 192.168.1.254;
option domain-name-servers 192.168.1.1, 192.168.1.2;
option domain-name "mydomain.example";

subnet 192.168.7.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 {
   range 192.168.7.10 192.168.7.25;
}
```

**EDIT:** Output of `sudo iptables -L`

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain FORWARD (policy DROP)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
LOG        all  --  anywhere             anywhere             LOG level warning

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

**Question:**

What crucial steps/components am I missing in this setup?

Comment: What dhcpd are you using?

Comment: @TML From my understanding `dhcp` (and thus `dhcpd`) is not mandatory, and is only meant for centralizing all static ips at the server (as opposed to changing the `/etc/network/interfaces` file in **every** host). Therefore, I have decided to not experiment with that until this works. I do however have `dhcp3-server` installed, as well as `isc-dhcp-server`

Comment: If you want the client to get an IP address from dhcp, you need to run a dhcpd; you should post the configuration for whichever of these dhcpd's is currently the active one, as that's where the source of the problem will be re: client not getting an IP. Personally, I would recommend dnsmasq, as it also brings with it some useful features for doing internal DNS resolution.

Comment: @TML I added the `dhcpd.conf` file and indicated that I am using `isc-dhcp-server`

Comment: Check the dhcpd's logfile to see if you're getting any DHCPREQUEST packets from the client; if you aren't, try giving a static IP in the 192.168.7.x range to the client, and see if it can even reach the router.

Comment: @TmL if Braiam's answer doesn't work, then I will try to get the log file working.

Comment: You should two more points:
5. I am sick and tired of having only partial control of the device.
6. I am sick and tired of having a router that could potentially have a backdoor.
Point #6 is a real thing that can be right now in any router. Some routers do come with extra features such as hard-coded password or secretly listening to some port.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I have to go like Jack the ripper due several missing things that you have:

1. If you client will use DHCP to get the IP's you need a DHCP server.

   > iface eth0 inet dhcp

   In the clients this indicates that they will get their IP's from a DHCP server, if you didn't setup a DHCP server, either you should use fixed IP's or install a DHCP server.
2. You lack of DNS servers configured in the clients. Either due the lack of DHCP server, or you may want to use a local DNS server for all your network.
3. You didn't offered the `iptables` rules (the output of `sudo iptables -L`) but I could guess that you didn't activated the Masquerade rules, nor IP forwarding [as described](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Router#Enable_IP_forwarding_and_Masquerading).
4. The IP address of `eth1` is not recommended. Any IP ended in `0` are typically the network itself, and [most routers/firewall just get confused when these are used](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14915188/792066). Change it to `192.168.7.1` and you will mostly fine.
5. Your `broadcast` value in the `eth1` interface is not correct. Is sending packages to nowhere. The correct value (taking into account other values of the interface) is `192.168.7.255`.
6. Your options in the DHCP server are vicious. The ARP packages to your router will never reach. This is what you should have:

   ```
   default-lease-time 600;
   max-lease-time 7200;
   option subnet-mask 255.255.255.0;
   option broadcast-address 192.168.7.255;
   option routers 192.168.7.1; ## This should be the same value of the step 4
   option domain-name-servers 8.8.8.8;

   subnet 192.168.7.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 {
       range 192.168.7.10 192.168.7.25;
   }
   ```

Follow these and most likely you will have your router working.

Comment: Added output of `sudo iptables -L` to question

Comment: Not to be picky, but for the interests of any one else reading this answer, could you explain what some of these dhcpd.conf values are: line 4 `192.168.7.255` and line 8 `subnet 192.168.7.0`

Comment: @puk that is too complex to explain in comments, but to put it nicely, `.255` is the normally used broadcast address, any package sent to that direction will be sent to all the systems in the same subnets. Meaning that any package sent to 1.2.3.255 it will be received by any system which IP's start with 1.2.3 since all of them are in the same subnet http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subnetwork#IPv4_subnetting

Comment: Not working. I want to see if the problem is `dhcp` or the network. Will do a static ip address to test. for the static ip on the client, do I use `eth1`'s ip address as the gateway?

Comment: light at the end of the tunnel, at least static ip works. Now to get dhcp to work

Comment: Yes, you use the eth1 ip in your clients as gateway. If you can ping your eth1 interface from the clients is a step closer, then try to ping your external gateway, if it doesn't work, then you have something wrong with the iptables rules.

Comment: I got static ip working, and I could ssh almost anywhere in either network (`eth0` or even the router network one step up) but I could not ssh from a computer in the router network into the `eth1` network (I just used proxy instead), but I still can't get `dhcp` to work. Do I need to set up anything else along with it?

Comment: Probably because the broadcast and network on eth1 of the router are pointing to 192.168.1.x instead of 192.168.7.x; if you can't talk from eth1 on router to eth0 on client, DHCPACKs won't ever arrive at client (and it'll consequently never get the IP).

Comment: @puk change your `eth1` interfaces file to `broadcast 192.168.7.255`.

Comment: @Braiam thank you. This is the kind of information I was looking for, otherwise, noobs like me end up making mistakes like these when plugging in values http://joi.ito.com/images2/mathjoke.gif

Comment: Changing `broadcast` to `192.168.7.255` did not fix the problem either

Comment: Wow I feel like an idiot, turns out I was changing `/etc/dhcp3/dhcpd.conf`

Answer (score 9):

Braiam answered my question, but I thought it would be helpful to put a thorough walkthrough here. Please update this if I have made any mistakes.

First make sure you have two ethernet cards (NICs) and update the `/etc/network/interfaces` file as such (do **not** mistake this for the `/etc/networks` file).

```
iface lo inet loopback                                                                                                                    

auto eth0
   iface eth0 inet static
   address 192.168.1.70
   netmask 255.255.255.0
   broadcast 192.168.1.255
   network 192.168.1.0
   gateway 192.168.1.1
   dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8

auto eth1
   iface eth1 inet static
   address 192.168.7.1
   netmask 255.255.255.0
   broadcast 192.168.7.255
   network 192.168.1.0
```

To find your `gateway`, `broadcast` and `network`, follow [these instructions](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/how-to-find-gateway-ip-address/).

Next, go into the client and edit the `/etc/network/interface` (again, **not** `/etc/networks`) file for static ip first, to make sure that at least the NIC card is working.

```
iface eth0 inet static
address 192.168.7.75
netmask 255.255.255.0
network 192.168.7.0
broadcast 192.168.7.255
gateway 192.168.7.1
```

Change the values to match up with the above values. If it works, great, then use the instructions [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/140126/how-do-i-configure-a-dhcp-server/184351#comment481661_184351) but follow them **exactly**, as there are several `dhcp` files so don't mistake the folder `/etc/dhcp` with `/etc/dhcp3` and so on.