# How do I make Ubuntu a router?

Tags: networking

I have an old install of Ubuntu 10.04, and I want to make it a router. I have a phone with 3g tethered to my computer via usb, and want to connect a Vonage box with ethernet.

Nexus
  4   ---------->> COMPUTER --------------->> Vonage

The network works on the internet, but vonage is unable to access the internet right now.

Please help!

EDIT: Here is the result of ifconfig -a:

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:24:e8:eb:a0:82  
      inet6 addr: fe80::224:e8ff:feeb:a082/64 Scope:Link
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:2460 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:1811 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
      RX bytes:942876 (942.8 KB)  TX bytes:212067 (212.0 KB)
      Interrupt:27 Base address:0x4000 

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
      inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
      inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
      UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
      RX packets:529 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:529 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
      RX bytes:45433 (45.4 KB)  TX bytes:45433 (45.4 KB)

usb0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 92:50:73:bb:25:38  
      inet addr:192.168.42.232  Bcast:192.168.42.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
      inet6 addr: fe80::9050:73ff:febb:2538/64 Scope:Link
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:3076 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:3913 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
      RX bytes:1597102 (1.5 MB)  TX bytes:692155 (692.1 KB)

wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 0c:ee:e6:9c:8a:62  
      UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
      RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
```

Comment: [Possible duplicate.](http://askubuntu.com/questions/376717/how-to-set-up-a-linux-server-as-a-router)

Comment: how could it be a duplicate? I registered 30 mins ago...

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/help/duplicates

Comment: I have tried many things already. tried editing /etc/network/interfaces and enabled forwarding. it doesn't work.

Comment: Nobody??? I'm disappointed with you guys. Moved to Fedora...