# How to setup and save vlans on ethernet

Tags: networking, ethernet

I am trying to setup vlans on my eth0 network card.  The following are the steps that I've taken:

1. Install `vlan` with `sudo apt-get install vlan`
2. Edit `/etc/network/interfaces` in vi by adding:

   ```
   auto eth0.100
   iface eth0.100 inet dhcp
   ```
3. Restarted networking and/or restarted Ubuntu
4. Ran `ifconfig`

I don't see the eth0.100 listed, I'm not sure what I am doing wrong.

I can add vlans using vconfig but they don't stay after a reboot.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

First you must install `vlan`

```
sudo apt-get install vlan
```

load kernel module

```
sudo modprobe 8021q
```

Create a new interface that is a member of a specific VLAN, VLAN id 100

We use the physical interface eth0 in this example.
This command will add an additional interface next to the interfaces which have been configured already

```
sudo vconfig add eth0 100
```

Assign an address to the new interface:

```
sudo ip addr add 10.0.0.1/24 dev eth0.100
```

To make this setup permanent. Add the module to the kernel on boot

```
sudo bash -c 'echo "8021q" >> /etc/modules'
```

Create the interface and make it available when the system boots. Add the following lines to `/etc/network/interfaces`

```
auto eth0.100
iface eth0.100 inet dhcp
    vlan-raw-device eth0
```

Comment: Why does the new interface need an IP assigned to it?  Could this step be skipped and the interface pickup a dynamic IP on the next boot?

Comment: Yes, can be skiped. This is only example. At the end on answer you have config for `eth0.100` for you.

Comment: You might need the `universe` repository to install `vlan`, but note that `vconfig` is deprecated now anyway.

Comment: I have [added an answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1407840/134479) explaining the 'modern day' solution using `ip link` and `netplan`.

Answer (score 1):

The modern way to create a VLAN interface is using `ip link` from iproute2.  Assuming you want to run the VLAN over interface eno1:

```
sudo ip link add link eno1 name vlan100 type vlan id 100
```

Now optionally give it an address:

```
sudo ip address add 10.0.0.100/24 dev vlan100
```

And bring it up:

```
sudo ip link set vlan100 up
```

To make this permanent, define the `vlan` interface in `/etc/netplan/*`. This will look like:

```
network:
    version: 2
    ethernets:
        eno1:
            ... eno1 config ...
    vlans:
        vlan100:
            id: 100
            link: eno1
            addresses: [10.0.0.100/24]
```

Detailed documentation is in the [netplan reference](https://netplan.io/reference/#properties-for-device-type-vlans%3A).