# 2 ubuntu dhcp servers

Tags: server, dhcp

I would like to run 2 DHCP servers at the same time, each one should have differnt IP but both in the same subnet, same gateway but one has to have the first half of the DHCP rang and the other the second half.

How should I do that (I can configure the servers, no problem) but shouldn't I point one to the other? if yes, then which command or how can I do it. (at the moment I have 2 window 2008 servers: 192 168.111.11 /24 with the first half of the range  and 192.168.111.20 /24 with the second half of the range and I had to point the 111.20 to be looking at the 111.11).

I would like to replace them with 2 ubuntu dhcp servers.

Many thanks in advance

Madona

Comment: Follow the steps in http://askubuntu.com/questions/140126/how-do-i-configure-a-dhcp-server and set the ranges to whatever you want them to be.

Answer (score 0):

I run two DHCP servers in one subnet at home (in case one box is not available).

In /etc/dhcp3/dhcpd.conf on the server I declare as the primary I have this:

```
failover peer "dhcp-failover" {
  primary; # declare this to be the primary server
  address 10.11.12.1;
  port 647;
  peer address 10.11.12.2;
  peer port 647;
  max-response-delay 30;
  max-unacked-updates 10;
  load balance max seconds 3;
  mclt 1800;
  split 128;
}
```

And in /etc/dhcp3/dhcpd.conf on the server I declare as the secondary I have this:

```
failover peer "dhcp-failover" {
  secondary; # declare this to be a secondary server
  address 10.11.12.2;
  port 647;
  peer address 10.11.12.1;
  peer port 647;
  max-response-delay 30;
  max-unacked-updates 10;
  load balance max seconds 3;
}
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Many Thanks Mark, will give it a try and report back.