# Wifi connects but internet not working on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS

Tags: wireless, internet

I have tried other solutions posted on this forum but nothing seems to work. Right now I am wired to the Internet. Please help.

Edit:

i) Command: lsb_release -a
Output:

```
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 12.04 LTS
Release:    12.04
Codename:   precise
```

ii) Command: lspci -nn | grep 0280
Output:

```
04:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Atheros Communications Inc. AR9285 Wireless Network Adapter (PCI-Express) [168c:002b] (rev 01)
```

iii) Command: sudo iwconfig
Output:

> lo        no wireless extensions.
>
> wlan0     IEEE 802.11bgn  ESSID:"welcome123"
>            Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.462 GHz  Access Point: 40:4A:03:BF:9A:01
>            Bit Rate=54 Mb/s   Tx-Power=16 dBm
>            Retry  long limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
>            Encryption key:off
>            Power Management:on
>            Link Quality=70/70  Signal level=-28 dBm
>            Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
>            Tx excessive retries:1  Invalid misc:58   Missed beacon:0>
>
> eth0      no wireless extensions.

iv) I tried connecting wifi to internet and it shows that I am connected. However, I am not able to access internet. So, basically my wifi is connected but internet is not working.

v) I tried 4-5 solutions posted here, none of them seems to work. I am new to Ubuntu so not really confident as to what exactly I did. But here are some links to posts I tried:

-- http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2218513
-- http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2218513
-- there was a solution posted by some user names chilli55 that I tried but am not able to find it again right now.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and include i) your version of Ubuntu; ii) your network card model and the driver you are using (run ` lspci -nn | grep 0280`) iii) the output of `sudo iwconfig` iv) explain your symptoms exactly. How does it connect? What do you try that fails? v) what are the solutions you tried? How did they fail?

Comment: hey terdon, I have updated question as you said.

Comment: Thanks for the update! That's much better. OK, how are you trying to access the internet? Do you mean that you can't see webpages? What's the output of `ping google.com`? It looks like everything is fine, can any other device connect to the internet wirelessly? Are you sure your router is set up correctly?

Comment: yes. My laptop is dual boot, internet works fine on Windows, which I have been using for the past couple of months. Tried connecting Ubuntu today and internet doesn't work. Yes, webpages don't load but wifi shows connected to the internet. Right now, I am wired with my ethernet cable.

Comment: Well, you don't have an IP. Have you set up your wireless connection to get an IP automatically (DHCP)? Do you have a DHCP service running on your router? Perhaps you have set up Windows with a static IP and that's why it works.

Comment: I think it's chili555; not chilli55! Do you have a conf file? cat /etc/modprobe.d/ath9k.conf Thanks!

Comment: Sorry chili555. No such file or directory.

Comment: hey terdon, I am checking for DHCP. Please wait a minute. I am going through steps given on this post http://askubuntu.com/questions/140126/how-do-i-configure-a-dhcp-server

Comment: hey terdon, I tried every step given on link provided in previous comment. Here are two things..  1) dhcp doesn't start 2) am i doing the right thing. I am new to this so I am not sure what I am doing. But I think there is some problem with DHCP only.

Comment: Please suggest something.

Comment: You need to ping a user if you want them to see your messages (for example, @chili555, see the OP's answer above). There is no need to configure a DHCP server on your computer, just make sure that your router has one. Check if your Windows connection is configured to get an IP automatically (DHCP) or not. Also, please [edit] your question to add all these extra details, they are easy to miss in the comments and comments can be deleted with no warning.

Comment: What's the output of `cat /etc/resolv.conf` when connected to wireless (no wired connection, plz) ?